# Collection id: By index or by value?

Tags: collections

Maybe I don't know what to search for this, but I tried "[json] id as index or value".

I am curious what others' experience teaches regarding this. I have a number of rest calls that return JSON data from a database. Among the values, are unique identifiers. My question is,

Is it better to provide the IDs as fields on the items, or as an index on items. For example:

```
{
    dataByValue: [
        { id: 1, data: "What's up?", otherData: "hi" },
        { id: 2, data: 123, otherData: "hi" }
    ],
    dataByIndex: {
        1: { data: "What's up?", otherData: "hi" },
        2: { data: 123, otherData: "hi" }
    },
    orMaybeBoth: {
        1: { id: 1, data: "What's up?", otherData: "hi" },
        2: { id: 2, data: 123, otherData: "hi" }
    }
}
```

I realize this is not valid JSON, but you get the picture.

I have some thoughts on why each may be beneficial:
By value may be easier to loop through, especially on platforms that don't have an easy way to handle variable keys on objects.

By index allows you to quickly access the data if you do have the ID.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with JSON. It's a matter of how to stucture data (that happens to be serialized as JSON at some point in its life). The answer will be bery specific to the data in question and usage thereof. Many opinions will be provided, none will be objectively correct. You need to get more specific about the problem you are solving. In the broadest sense the first is a more common representation of a collection esp in context of REST. But YMMV depending on the actual situation.